# weblogic does not deploy web service/war properly

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, weblogic, war, maven-ear-plugin

Running WLS 12.1.3 with NB 8.1 and a maven project.  We have an ear with ejbs and a web service.  If we build the ear as an open directory deployment ( war is a open directory), when it is deployed
to the server, the web service does not appear under the "Web Services" in the deployment under admin console.  This is with the maven-ear plugin and unpack element set to true:

```
       <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.hsntech</groupId>
                        <artifactId>HansenIntegrationFramework-web</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/HansenIntegrationFramework-web</contextRoot>
                  <unpack>true</unpack> 
                    </webModule>
```

However if I set unpack to false, and the war portion of the ear is then put into a .war file, the deployment does show the web service in the admin console.  Any clue on why the different behavior?  Defect?  I looked at the contents of the jar'd .war file, and it is the same as the open war directory.